How to set minimum to auto increment using kysely?
I want to translate below code to kysely, but I can't figure out how to set minimum to auto-increment, and also how to set char length?
CREATE TABLE `users` 
(
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `last_name` CHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `password` CHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1000001;

I can translate it till here:
  await db.schema
    .createTable("users")
    .addColumn("id", "integer", col => col.primaryKey().unsigned().notNull().autoIncrement())
    .addColumn("first_name", "char", col => col.notNull())
    .addColumn("last_name", "char", col => col.notNull())
    .addColumn("password", "char", col => col.notNull())
    .execute();


change integer -> int(8)  and  char -> char(50)
